# How to handle Async function response in react native and save in useState?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, firebase, react-native

```js
const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(null);

const signIn = async phoneNumber => {
  console.log('Entered into signIn Function');
  setTextInputState(false);
  setSendOtpButtonState(true);

  const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
  console.log('This is conformation1' + JSON.stringify(confirmation));
  setSendOtpButtonState(true);
  setOtpInputState(true);

  let res = confirmation;
  setConfirm(res);

  console.log('This is conformation2' + JSON.stringify(confirm));
};
```

How to set conformation in the useState . when we enter into the signIn function for the first time getting useState value as null and for the second time setting the value in the useState . i want to set value for the first time.

Comment: share full component, I think in that case you need `useEffect` as well.

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
const signIn = async (phoneNumber) => {

  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(null);
  ...

  useEffect(async () => {
    const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    console.log("This is conformation1" + JSON.stringify(confirmation));
    setSendOtpButtonState(true);
    setOtpInputState(true);

    let res = confirmation;
    setConfirm(res);
  }, []);

  console.log("This is conformation2" + JSON.stringify(confirm));
};
```

Comment: i got this error. Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: i updated with your code sir but its not working

Comment: Still same issue? Invalid Hook call ?

Comment: same issue sir .